# Sharing > Remote Management and network security

Tags: network, remote-desktop

I need to "rdp" into my mac mini on my local network from my windows machine, to do this I simply enabled Remote Management, downloaded VNC viewer on windows and then connected, viola!... Except it is not encrypted; which is fine because I trust my local network.

However, I need to understand, in doing this, am I opening up any security concerns? I do not assume so but wanted to be sure as I do not understand Apple's remote management features entirely. Basically, I want to be sure I am not exposing my local network through my mac mini when I enabled this feature.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be, no.

But that may depend on whether you are then also internet connected on your Winbox at the time you're VNCing into the Mac, especially if you're using IE, even more so if you're using IE with .net framework applications, or even more exposed, Active X as well.

You *could* potentially end up exposing the Mac to attack via the VNC connection if your Win box were compromised.